# Spring Data Jpa @query behaviours

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Can anybody please tell me @Query annotation will support DB independence query mechanism

Example:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query("select u from User u where u.firstname like %?1")
  List<User> findByFirstnameEndsWith(String firstname);
}
```

if i write this query will it support all the DBs like Mysql,oracle, postgres.

i found something like this in spring data jpa reference document site that

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
  User findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);
```

here is this means if i write nativeQuery=true it will treat as native query and if don't writer it will behave like a spring data jpa specific query or how it will behave please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the nativeQuery flag to true, the query is treated as native sql whose behaviour will depend on DB host.If you dont set nativeQuery=true, then it is treated as JPQL and the real query for DB is generated by JPA according to the DB host hence it is DB independent.